# why incremented value is coming as null after end of loop?

Tags: oracle

V_TOTAL_SIZE_MB values are coming within the loop but when I try to print V_TOTAL_SIZE_GB is coming as null after loop or inside the loop.

```
DECLARE
  V_TOTAL_SIZE_MB NUMBER;
  V_TOTAL_SIZE_GB NUMBER := 0.0;

  CURSOR c1
      IS 
      select NODE_ID from dept where id=12;
BEGIN

  FOR c1_rec IN c1
  LOOP

   SELECT SUM(round(u.size/1024/1024,2)) 
     INTO V_TOTAL_SIZE_MB
     from child 
    WHERE =c1_rec.NODE_ID;

    V_TOTAL_SIZE_GB := V_TOTAL_SIZE_GB+V_TOTAL_SIZE_MB;

    dbms_output.put_line(':::V_TOTAL_SIZE_MB:'|| V_TOTAL_SIZE_MB);

   END LOOP;
   dbms_output.put_line(':::TOTAL_SIZE_GB:'|| V_TOTAL_SIZE_GB/1024);
END;
```

Comment: It's possible that in one of the iteration your query returns NULL. If where condition evaluates to false NO_DATA_FOUND exception will not be raised because of the presence of SUM() aggregate function. NULL will be returned thus `V_TOTAL_SIZE_GB + NULL= NULL`

Comment: thanks for pinpoint the problem.